# How to test internet speed (JavaSE)?

Tags: java

Is there a way to test internet speed using Java code?

For instance, like how we actually test with cmd command, ping command.

Comment: Most internet speed tests write a file to a remote server, then read the file back.  They will sometimes use three different size files (1kb, 100kb, 1gb) to measure transfer speed.

Answer (score 4):

use **JSpeedTest** Library

```
SpeedTestSocket speedTestSocket = new SpeedTestSocket();

// add a listener to wait for speedtest completion and progress
speedTestSocket.addSpeedTestListener(new ISpeedTestListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(SpeedTestReport report) {
        // called when download/upload is complete
        System.out.println("[COMPLETED] rate in octet/s : " + report.getTransferRateOctet());
        System.out.println("[COMPLETED] rate in bit/s   : " + report.getTransferRateBit());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SpeedTestError speedTestError, String errorMessage) {
         // called when a download/upload error occur
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(float percent, SpeedTestReport report) {
        // called to notify download/upload progress
        System.out.println("[PROGRESS] progress : " + percent + "%");
        System.out.println("[PROGRESS] rate in octet/s : " + report.getTransferRateOctet());
        System.out.println("[PROGRESS] rate in bit/s   : " + report.getTransferRateBit());
    }
});
```